# How do I create a removable foreign key?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, relational-algebra

Basically the situation is like this (simplified, pseudo code):

I have 2 TABLES person and country.

Person table:

```
KEY INT ID, STRING NAME, STRING COUNTRY
```

Country table:

```
KEY INT ID, STRING COUNTRY_NAME
```

The client has control over what the contents are in the Country Table, so he can add and remove counties to the list. This country values appear in a drop down list when creating a person. When the person is created the country strings value is inserted in the country column of the Person row.

To me, it makes sense that that Person should have a foreign key reference to country, but because the client has control over what appears in the Country table, they are kept as separate tables, because you can't just remove used countries, (referential integrity and all). This is an argument a colleague of mine made to not use foreign keys in this case, but I feel like there should be a better solution for this problem, So, is my colleague right or is there a better solution?

The client can add and remove values in the country table but if a value is removed from the country table, created person who used that value should keep their value.

Comment: Maybe instead of actually deleting the row, you could have a column for that "isActive" or something and when the client deletes the country, set "isActive" to 0. That way you can still maintain referential integrity but client still has control over what countries are displayed.

Comment: "The client can add and remove values in the country table" -- you are putting the cart before the horse :) That is an implementation consideration. What is the business rule being modelled?

Comment: I think the business rule would be something like:
"The client has control over which values the user can put into the country column" so, the client has no control over changing the values already have been put in.

Comment: Forget the database for the moment: what is the user-understood meaning of the rule? 'Column' is a DBMS-understood meaning, assuming the enterprise is not in the business writing a regular geopolitical newspaper feature or manufacturing pillars for nation states or similar ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an isactive column, the data for historical records will then show the county chosen orginally (or it's updated value, see below) and the drop down list can be adjusted to only show the active countries. Under no circumstances should you remove the foreign key constraint. That is a recipe for data integrity issues.

The setting to null idea is generally a bad one as well. You do not want to lose data about the country the person is in.

If the country might change (as opposed to new countries being added), then you can use cascade update, but it is better in this case to use a surrogate key (which should not change). Then if the name is changed, it is reflected everywhere without having to update millions of child records.

Comment: "it is better in this case to use a surrogate key" -- no because that wouldn't prevent duplicates e.g. my own country's name, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, would likely be duplicated as 'UK', 'Britain', 'England', etc. Better to use [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_currency_codes) codes or similar identifier with a trusted source.

Comment: Yes, but I'm searching more for a "genera" solution rather than one that applies to the "Country" column specifically.

Comment: @onedaywhen, not if they are going to change and many records woudl need to change.I too use the country codes but inthis case the users were actually cahnging the countries, so the ISO country codes seemed out of place here. And I would still use a surrogate key if you havea lot of records. That way when the Untied States changes it's name to something else, you don't have to change every address out of millions of records.

Comment: "when the Untied States changes it's name" -- either your tongue is firmly embedded in cheek or a classic [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it) ;) Clearly, neither users nor clients get to rename nation states in the real world!

Comment: Countries change names (maybe not daily, true but usually several in a year) - I used the US as an example of how it would affect your database if you store the country name anywhere except the loopkup table because that is a country likely to have many records and cause a massive user lockout if you rely on cascading updates. You have to plan to avoid this stuff in database design unles you want unhappy users.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify as an option to the `FOREIGN KEY` what to to when a record of the referenced table is deleted: `ON DELETE ([RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION])` (These are the option available in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)).

In general you should use foreign keys. For example, why should it be possible to delete a country if persons refer to it? Wihtout a foreign key you need to manually check for references.

In you example I wouls also use the ID field of the country as a refernce. You can rhen change the name of a country and all persons which reference the ID will get this information (Sure, you will need a join).

Another solution for this update would be to specify an `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option to the original foreign key, resulting in an update of all `Country` fields of the corresponding persons when changing the name of a country.

Answer (score 0):

Database are already designed to handle removal of records still referenced by foreign keys.

You should still use a foreign key, and specify how you want it to behave with `on delete`. If you want to allow records (countries) still referenced (by persons) to be removed, use

```
foreign key country_id references countries(id)
    on delete set null;
```

If you want the foreign key to *prevent* referenced countries from disappearing, leave off the `on delete` clause and attempts to delete countries that are still referenced will fail. This is typically desired behaviour; attempts to put the database into an invalid state *should* fail.

Whether the associated record's foriegn key is set to `null`, or the referenced record's deletion is prevented, the foreign key still enforces and maintains referential integrity. That's their job, and they're pretty good at it.